# How do I write this query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table called `Album` with the following attributes: `Title`, `Artist`, `Year`, `Type`, `Rating`.
The `type` can only be `LIVE` or `STUDIO`. So how can I get the artists who released both `LIVE and STUDIO` album in the *same yea*r? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **self join**.

```
SELECT A.Artist
    FROM 
    Album A
    INNER JOIN Album B ON A.Artist=B.Artist AND A.Year=B.Year
    WHERE A.Type='LIVE' AND B.Type='STUDIO'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH Alb AS 
(SELECT
    Year,Type,Artist
FROM
    Album
GROUP BY
    Year,Type,Artist)
SELECT
    AlbA.Year
    ,AlbA.Artist
FROM
    Alb AlbA
    INNER JOIN Alb AlbB ON AlbA.Year = AlbB.Year AND AlbA.Artist = AlbB.Artist
WHERE 
    AlbA.Type = 'Live'
    AND AlbB.Type = 'Studio'
```